# Can not read csv with pandas in azure functions with python

Tags: python, pandas, azure

I have created an Azure Blob Storage Trigger in Azure function in python.
A CSV file adds in blob storage and I try to read it with pandas.

```
import logging
import pandas as pd

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

    df_new = pd.read_csv(myblob)
    print(df_new.head())
```

If I pass `myblob` to `pd.read_csv`, then I get `UnsupportedOperation: read1`

```
Python blob trigger function processed blob 
Name: samples-workitems/Data_26112022_080027.csv
Blob Size: None bytes
[2022-11-27T16:19:25.650Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Failed, Id=2df388f5-a8dc-4554-80fa-f809cfaeedfe, Duration=1472ms)
[2022-11-27T16:19:25.655Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTrigger1. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: UnsupportedOperation: read1
```

If I pass `myblob.read()`,

```
df_new = pd.read_csv(myblob.read())
```

it gives `TypeError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type`

```
Python blob trigger function processed blob 
Name: samples-workitems/Data_26112022_080027.csv
Blob Size: None bytes
[2022-11-27T16:09:56.513Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Failed, Id=e3825c28-7538-4e30-bad2-2526f9811697, Duration=1468ms)
[2022-11-27T16:09:56.518Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTrigger1. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: TypeError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

From [Azure functions Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.inputstream?view=azure-python#:%7E:text=File%2Dlike%20object%20representing%20an%20input%20blob.):

> InputStream is File-like object representing an input blob.

From [Pandas read_csv Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#:%7E:text=path%20object%20or-,file%2Dlike%20object,-Any%20valid%20string):

> read_csv takes filepath_or_bufferstr, path object or **file-like object**

So technically I should read this object. What piece of puzzle am I missing here?

Comment: The pd.read_csv function should get a file name with path. What does myblob contain?

Comment: I uploaded Data_26112022_080027.csv

Comment: `Python blob trigger function processed blob`

`Name: samples-workitems/Data_26112022_080027.csv`

`Blob Size: None bytes`

Comment: This is the output before exception occured.

Comment: I added the output to question as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/832), it says that this piece of code will work. But this is recommended for smaller files as the entire files goes into memory. Not recommended to be used for larger files.

```
import logging
import pandas as pd

import azure.functions as func
from io import BytesIO

def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    df_new = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(myblob.read()))
    print(df_new.head())
```

Comment: my files are smaller than 10mbs, so I guess no memory issue for me.